# How to create dynamic url in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

Right now when i hit below URL ,

angularproj.localhost.com

it will open login page and above url will be changed to

angularproj.localhost.com/#/login . This is the admin login

Now as per my project requirement , i will have multiple customers and all those will have their logins.

So i need create seperate URLs for them.

Say first customer is C1.So my url will be angularproj.localhost.com/c1.

And when i hit angularproj.localhost.com/c1 in browser it should open c1 customer login page.

I have tried below but no luck.

$stateProvider

```
    .state('/:customer', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "app/views/login/Customer/login.html",
        data: { pageTitle: 'Example view' }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying this way. It should work.

```
var app = angular.module('tutorialWebApp', [
' ngRoute'
]);

/**
* Configure the Routes
*/

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            // Home
            .when("/", {templateUrl: "partials/home.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
            // Pages
            .when("/about", {templateUrl: "partials/about.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
            // else 404
            .otherwise("/404", {templateUrl: "partials/404.html", controller: "PageCtrl"});
}]);
```

Comment: I tries this but when i hit http://angularproj.localhost.com/about , it is giving 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynamic templateUrl in your router

example:

```
.state('login', {
  url: '/{customerID}',
  views: {
    'menu': {
        templateUrl:
                 function (stateParams){
                    return '/partials/login' + stateParams.customerID+ '.html';
            }
    }
  }
})
```